# What are the odds of having to see a UK immigration agent for someone eligible to use the e-gates?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, statistics

According to [the UK government](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coming-to-the-uk/faster-travel-through-the-uk-border):

> You can normally use eGates if you are either:
>
> - a British citizen
> - a national of an EU country, Australia, Canada, Iceland, Japan, Liechtenstein, New Zealand, Norway, Singapore, South Korea,
>   Switzerland or the USA
> - a member of the Registered Traveller Service

Are there any statistics available to show how often those eligible to use the e-Gates end up having to see a UK immigration officer? The UK entry interview can be nerve wracking for travelers who are not experienced with strict border controls, so its very much relevant to EU travelers who will now find themselves traveling to the UK for the first time without the comfort of knowing they'll be granted entry on account of their EU citizenship.

Comment: I’m not sure how useful this data, if it exists, would currently be to most EU, EEA and Swiss citizens. Until 1 October 2021, entry with just a national ID card was allowed https://www.gov.uk/government/news/insecure-id-cards-phased-out-as-travel-document-to-strengthen-uk-borders but that meant forgoing use of the e-gates.

Comment: @PeterM all EU citizens are eligible to use the e-gates.

Comment: @Traveller I assume there could be stats for other nationalities on how often they're asked to see an immigration officer after using the e-gate?

Comment: My bad about the EU citizens.  But  given that there is always a possibility for interacting with an immigration officer, a traveler will always have to be 100% prepared to do so.  So that makes the question moot IMHO

Comment: @JonathanReez Can’t find anything so far. There’s this https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/border-force-transparency-data-q1-2021 and this https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/immigration-statistics-year-ending-june-2021 for example but I don’t see any reference to e-gate data

Comment: Asking about "odds" suggests there is some random process going on but it may be that people are instead sent to the IO by the machine due to known derogatory information and/or profiling and/or some other systemic decision making such that the probability is 0% for most and 100% for a few. In this case they may also not be keen to publish any information about this for fear of revealing something about that algorithm.

Comment: To add, I'm a non-EU national who has used the e-Gates more than a dozen times since 2016 and never had one fail to open. My wife, who has used them at least as many times, did have a gate not open once early on but the IO's only concern seemed to be why the gate didn't open (as if his computer was telling him it should have?) and, after checking that the passport's digital picture matched her, he asked no questions.